# Should I use database trigger in insert heavy operation table?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

My use-case is that I need to copy a few columns from TABLE A to another TABLE B and also derive values of a few other columns of TABLE B by some calculation.

As per current estimation around 50,000 rows will be inserted on daily basis in TABLE A.

TABLE B should be updated with all data before End of day.

Hence, either I can use trigger which will be invoked on INSERT operation on TABLE A or schedule some Job at EOD which read all data in bulk from TABLE A , do some calculation and insert in TABLE B.

As I am new to trigger, I am not sure which option should i pick for this use-case. Any suggestion which would be a better approach ?

So far what I have read about triggers, they can slow down DBs performance if they are invoked frequently.

As around 50,000 insert operation will happen daily , so can I assume that 50,000 falls under heavy operations where triggers would not be beneficial ?

EDIT 1 : 50,000 insert operation will reach 100,000 insert operations daily

Postgres DB is used.

Comment: As you need the data in Table B at a scheduled time only then Scheduled job will be always better. Triggers should be used if you need data in Table B simultaneously.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra Not scheduled time but before EOD , all data should get replicated in Table B

Comment: EOD means within working hours? if yes then there are 2 cases. 1. If you are stopping the insertion in TableA before EOD at fix time and then planning to transmit the values in TableB at fix time then scheduler is better 2. if you can not comply point 1 then go for triggers.

Comment: 50000 insertions over 8 hours is not that much. If you write the trigger well then the slowing down of the `insert` will not be noticed. Go for the trigger. You will have one concern to worry about less.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm if 50000 reaches to 100,000 over 8 hours, can I still use trigger ?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I think I won't be able to use trigger because if suppose no transaction happen on 1 day then use case is to copy previous day last transaction which is not possible with trigger.

Comment: I think 100000 and even more would be still fine for a simple `after insert for each row` trigger. However I do not like at all copying last day's last transaction if there are no transactions for the day. Data is data, it should be clean and correct. If there are no transactions then there shall be no records. Think about implementing your last day logic in the extraction query. But keep the data clean.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing bulk COPY into an unindexed table, adding a simple trigger will slow you down by a lot (like 5 fold).  But if you are using single-row INSERTs or the table is indexed, the marginal slow down of adding a simple trigger will be pretty small.

50,000 inserts per day is not very many.  You should have no trouble using a trigger on that, unless the trigger has to scan a large table on each call or something.

Comment: After reconfirming, I got to know that 50,000 may go upto 100,000. Do you still think trigger is a good choice if my target table have indexes ?

Comment: I think I won't be able to use trigger because if suppose no transaction happen on 1 day then use case is to copy previous day last transaction which is not possible with trigger.